# UISwitch in Prototype Cell with multiple rows only referenced to the last row. WHY

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, swift2

Okay so I have been working on this for a couple days now and everything I have tried does not work.

Here is the problem:
I have two prototype cells both with `subclasses`in my `UITableView` the first prototype cell has one element. The second prototype cell has rows with a `Strings` and `UISwitch` in each row. I'm trying to save the individual user influenced `UISwitch` in `NSUSerDefaults`. I have a `NSDictionary` to store `String and Bool` this dictionary stores the state of the switch as a bool. In the superclass I use a `for loop` to iterate through the dictionary and so that I can evaluate the `UISwitch state`.  But the problem is when I flip a `UISwitch` to the on position, the Dictionary records the `UISwitch` state but references it to last element.

Example:

Lets say I have four rows in the second prototype. I flip the `UISwitch` in row 0 to on, the row number that is recorded is the 3(the last element). I know this because I put a print line in the code to print the row that is referenced when any `UISwitch` is flipped every single time regardless of row the print line returned the last row number.

Not sure how to get this to reference individually, any help is appreciated.

Here is my Code:

This is the Subclass:

```
cellNumber = rowNumber

        if mySwitch.on{

            savedItems["switchKey"] = true

            print(cellNumber)

        }else{

            savedItems["switchKey"] = false


        }
}
```

This is the SuperClass:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return objects.count + staticObjects.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row < staticObjects.count {

        let staticCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("staticCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StaticTableViewCell

        staticCell.staticTitleLabel.text = self.staticObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String


        return staticCell

    }

    else{

        let row = indexPath.row - staticObjects.count

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PillarTableViewCell

        cell.titleLabel.text = self.objects.objectAtIndex(row) as? String

        theSwitch = cell.mySwitch

        rowNumber = indexPath.row

        for (key,value) in savedItems{

            if value == true {

                cell.mySwitch.setOn(true, animated: true)
            }

        } 
return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simple mistake:

```
rowNumber = indexPath.row
```

this line will ensure that `rowNumber` is set to the index path. In fact, it will be set to the index path of the last cell. When first cell is requested through `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it is assigned to 0 then for next row it is assigned to 1, etc.

What you want to do instead is to assign a tag to each of your switches equal to the row of the cell:

```
cell.mySwitch.tag = indexPath.row
```

then rewrite your saving function:

```
cellNumber = mySwitch.tag

        if mySwitch.on{

            savedItems["switchKey"] = true

            print(cellNumber)

        }else{

            savedItems["switchKey"] = false


        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much that helped me a ton, this has been weighing on me for days.  I do have another question. The Dictionary I setup `savedItems["switchKey"] = true`. It records that value for every switch, it does not associate the row number to each `UISwitch` why is that?  Thanks for the help, I really appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: @Rico why would it associate the value with each individual switch? :) You have a dictionary and you update one of its values. You are always updating the SAME value, so of course it will lead to the same value being read. If you want to store values for individual switches you can use "switchKey\\(cellNumber)" as your key.

Comment: Absolutely correct. I changed the dictionary to `var savedItems = [Int : Bool]()` then put `[cellNumber]` as the key so that it will create a key and bool value for every row. I did exactly what you are saying last night after you helped me the first time. I'm glad you went about making the key value the same as I did. So now I'm trying to set the `UISwitch`  based off of `NSDicitionary` values `true` on `false` off. I'm trying a `switch case` approach but it doesn't seem to be working. Any thoughts? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Got it handled had to put an `if` statement in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` section to prevent dictionary from being read each time a row is created. Thanks so much for your help I really would still be stuck without the `.tag` correction you gave me. Thanks again.